# HTML5 history API: cannot go backwards more than once

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I have been trying to get my script working but apparently there is something wrong with it: when I try to go backwards with the browser back button, it stops at the first page backwards i.e. the second time I click the back button, does not work properly and instead updates the current page with itself.

Examples:
homepage -> second page -> third page -> second page -> second page -> second page (and so on)

homepage -> second page -> third page -> fourth page -> third page-> third page (and so on)

This instead works:
homepage -> second page -> homepage

Does anyone have a clue to what I am missing?

```
var domain = 'http://example.com/';

function updatePage(json){
    var postData = JSON.parse(json);

    // pushState 
    var url = domain + postData.url;
    var title = postData.title;
    document.title = title;
    history.pushState({"page": url}, title, url);

    // Clears some elements and fills them with the new content
    // ...

    // Creates an 'a' element that triggers AJAX for the next post
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = postData.next;
    a.href = domain + postData.next;
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild( a );
    listenerAttacher( a );

    // Creates another 'a' element that triggers AJAX for the previous post
    a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = postData.previous;
    a.href = domain + postData.previous;
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild( a );
    listenerAttacher( a );
}


function loadPost( resource ){
    // Loads post data through AJAX using a custom function
    loadHTML( resource, function(){
        updatePage( this.responseText );
    });
}

function listenerAttacher( element ){
    // Adds a click listener to an element. 
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        loadPost( this.href +'.json' );
        return false;
    }, 
    false);
}


(function(){
    history.replaceState({'page': window.location.href}, null, window.location.href);

    // Adds the event listener to all elements that require it.
    var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.post-title');
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        listenerAttacher( titles[i] );
    }

    // Adds a popstate listener
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
        if ( e.state == null || e.state.page == domain ){
            window.location = domain;

        }
        else {
            loadPost( e.state.page + '.json' );
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pressed back button, `popstate` event is fired and `loadPost` function is called. However in `loadPost`, `history.pushState` method is called again, which pushes the current page on the history stack again. Which explains why the first back button works and then it does not.

1) A quick fix is to check if the current state matches the state you are trying to push:

```
if (!history.state || history.state.page!=url)
    history.pushState({ "page": url }, title, url);
```

2) Event better, you can add parameter to `loadPost` and `updatePage` functions to prevent unnecessary `pushState` calls:

```
function updatePage(json, disablePushState) {
    ...
    // disablePushState is true when back button is pressed
    // undefined otherwise
    if (!disablePushState)  
        history.pushState({ "page": url }, title, url);
    ...
}


function loadPost(resource, disablePushState) {
    // Loads post data through AJAX using a custom function
    loadHTML(resource, function (responseText) {
        updatePage(responseText, disablePushState);
    });
}

    ...
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
        if (e.state == null || e.state.page == domain) {
            window.location = domain;
        }
        else {
            loadPost(e.state.page + '.json', true);
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Hope this help.